# Changing pathData doesn't work (VectorDrawable)

Tags: android, android-animation, android-vectordrawable

I'm trying to animate VectorDrawable path morphing, but for some reason path morphing is the only thing that doesn't work (changing color, etc works OK). 
This is my Drawable:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:viewportWidth="170"
    android:viewportHeight="170"
    android:width="500dp"
    android:height="500dp">
    <path
        android:name="head"
        android:fillColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:pathData="M85,40
                          c10,0 20,0 30,0
                          c0,-5 -10,-20 -30,-20
                          c-20,0 -30,15 -30,20
                          c10,0 20,0 30,0"/>
</vector>
```

AnimatedVectorDrawable:

```
<animated-vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:drawable="@drawable/vector_drawable">
<target
    android:animation="@animator/path_morph"
    android:name="head"/>
</animated-vector>
```

And the animation itself:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:ordering="sequentially">
<objectAnimator
    android:duration="200"
    android:propertyName="pathData"
    android:valueType="pathType"
    android:valueFrom="M85,40
                  c10,0 20,0 30,0
                  c0,-5 -10,-20 -30,-20
                  c-20,0 -30,15 -30,20
                  c10,0 20,0 30,0"
    android:valueTo="M108,35
c5.587379,-6.7633 9.348007,-16.178439 8.322067,-25.546439
c-8.053787,0.32369 -17.792625,5.36682 -23.569427,12.126399
c-5.177124,5.985922 -9.711121,15.566772 -8.48777,24.749359
c8.976891,0.69453 18.147476,-4.561718 23.73513,-11.329308"/>
<objectAnimator
    android:duration="200"
    android:propertyName="fillColor"
    android:valueFrom="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:valueTo="@color/colorAccent"
    />
</set>
```

This is how I start animation:

```
((Animatable)binding.image.getDrawable()).start();
```

What's wrong?

### Update

Looks like I found something: it'll work if I set it to `TextView` ('bottomDrawable' for example), or set it to `ImageView`, but as `android:src` and not `app:srcCompat`. Is it a bug?

Comment: Have you enabled the VectorDrawable support library, and are there any messages or errors in the log when it's running?

Comment: @LewisMcGeary Yes, support VectorDrawable is enabled. And no, there is no errors in logs.

Comment: @LewisMcGeary Looks like I found something. If I set this Drawable to TextView (bottomDrawable for example), all will animate as normal, but if I set this Drawable as a srcCompat to AppCompatImageView then it wouldn't work.

Comment: Odd, I think this is to do with wether the support library version is being used or not, because that doesn't really work with path morphing. I guess srcCompat causes `AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat` to be used and the others use the system `AnimatedVectorDrawable`. Don't really know exactly what's happening though.

Comment: Note that `pathData` morphing does not work on pre-Lollipop devices. Which Android API are you using?

Comment: @ahasbini A'm using API 23